# Get facebook email after login in Android

Tags: android, json, facebook, email

Here is my code realising the connection.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner;
import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner.RequestListener;
import com.facebook.android.DialogError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;
import com.facebook.android.Util;

public class FacebookConnect extends Activity{

    public static final String TAG = "FACEBOOK";
    private Facebook mFacebook;
    public static final String APP_ID = "XXX";
    private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
    private static final String[] PERMS = new String[] { "read_stream" };
        private SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
        private Context mContext; 

        private TextView username;
        private ProgressBar pb;
        String fbId, fbName, fbEmail;

        public void setConnection() {
                mContext = this;
                mFacebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
                mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);
        }

        public void getID(TextView txtUserName, ProgressBar progbar) {
                username = txtUserName;
                pb = progbar;
                if (isSession()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "sessionValid");
                        mAsyncRunner.request("me", new IDRequestListener());
                } else {
                    // no logged in, so relogin
                    Log.d(TAG, "sessionNOTValid, relogin");
                        mFacebook.authorize(this, PERMS, new LoginDialogListener());
                }
        }

        public boolean isSession() {
                sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
                String access_token = sharedPrefs.getString("access_token", "x");
            Long expires = sharedPrefs.getLong("access_expires", -1);
                Log.d(TAG, access_token);

                if (access_token != null && expires != -1) {
                        mFacebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
                        mFacebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
                }
                return mFacebook.isSessionValid();
        }

        private class LoginDialogListener implements DialogListener {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "LoginONComplete");
                    String token = mFacebook.getAccessToken();
                    long token_expires = mFacebook.getAccessExpires();
                    Log.d(TAG, "AccessToken: " + token);
                    Log.d(TAG, "AccessExpires: " + token_expires);
                    sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
                                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
                    sharedPrefs.edit().putLong("access_expires", token_expires).commit();
                    sharedPrefs.edit().putString("access_token", token).commit();
                    mAsyncRunner.request("me", new IDRequestListener());
                }

                @Override
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "FacebookError: " + e.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(DialogError e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                        Log.d(TAG, "OnCancel");
                }
        }

        private class IDRequestListener implements RequestListener {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                        try {
                                Log.d(TAG, "IDRequestONComplete");
                            Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                                JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
                                fbId = json.getString("id");
                                fbName = json.getString("name");
                                //fbEmail = json.getString("email");

                                FacebookConnect.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                    username.setText("Welcome: " + name + "\n ID: " + fbId);
                                pb.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                                    }
                            });
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "JSONException: " + e.getMessage());
                    } catch (FacebookError e) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "FacebookError: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                }

                @Override
                public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                                Object state) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                                Object state) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "FacebookError: " + e.getMessage());
                }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                mFacebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
}
```

As a response I get a JSON. Example:

```
08-15 14:22:42.160: DEBUG/FACEBOOK(1258): Response: {"id":"3159628280","name":"Peter Black","first_name":"Peter","last_name":"Black","link":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/Peter.Black","username":"Peter.Black","gender":"male","timezone":3,"locale":"bg_BG","verified":true,"updated_time":"2011-08-14T08:42:59+0000"}
```

My question is how can I get the user's email (the email with which he logs into Facebook)?

Comment: dude u got email address of facebook users i am trying but not getting List of email addresses.

Comment: Not sure if I get you right, but down here (the answer) is how I got the email address.

Comment: dude i am telling u that i want to fetch email addresses of all Facebook users

Comment: You cannot obtain the all the emails in a cycle using the method shown below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need the `email` permission to read the users email adress.
That will add a email tag in your json-response from `[uid]` or `me` requests.

**email**

> Provides access to the user's primary email address in the email
>   property. Do not spam users. Your use of email must comply both with
>   Facebook policies and with the CAN-SPAM Act.

Source: [Permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/)

Comment: Thanks, it worked! If this post is useful to someone - the permission goes here:
`private static final String[] PERMS = new String[] { "read_stream", "email" };`

Comment: dude help me to get facebook user email addresses

Comment: does the code above gets the user details(email, firstname, lastname etc..,) if he is logged in to facebook ??

Comment: how can u get the profile pic of the user?? is it possible to get the url??

Answer (score 1):

Do it when you are clicking Login button:

```
  OpenRequest openRequest = new OpenRequest(this);
  List<String> readPermissions = new ArrayList<String>();
  readPermissions.add("email");
  openRequest.setPermissions(readPermissions);
  openRequest.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK);
  openRequest.setCallback(statusCallback);
  session.openForRead(openRequest);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option to retrieve email in Facebook SDK 3.0.x is by using this open source library: 
**android-simple-facebook** 
 https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook

- First, use this permission

  ```
  Permissions.EMAIL
  ```
- Then, login

  ```
  mSimpleFacebook.login(MainActivity.this);
  ```
- And then, get the profile

  ```
  mSimpleFacebook.getProfile(new OnProfileRequestAdapter()
  {
      @Override
      public void onComplete(Profile profile)
      {
          String id = profile.getId();
          String firstName = profile.getFirstName();
          String birthday = profile.getBirthday();
          String email = profile.getEmail();
          String bio = profile.getBio();
          // ... and many more properties of profile ...
      }
  });
  ```

Full examples are [**explained here**](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook#usage) including permissions stuff and other simplified methods (like: publish feeds, get friends and more...)

Answer (score 1):

Before calling Session.openActiveSession do this to get permissions add this:

```
List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
permissions.add("email");
```

The last parameter in `Session.openActiveSession()` should be permissions. Now you can access `user.getProperty("email").toString()`.